# Chocolatey not Working with PowerShell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

So, I got chocolatey up and running. But, I noticed that the cmdlets are not working. As in, if try to do anything using choco commands; ex: `choco install vlc`, it works just fine. However, if I try using good old cmdlets;
ex: `Install-Package -Name vlc -Source chocolatey`,
it keeps giving me angry warnings about not finding the chocolatey-core.extension.

The letteral message is:-

```
WARNING: NuGet: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '1.3.5.1' of package
'chocolatey-core.extension'.
WARNING: NuGet:    at NuGet.PackageRepositoryHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository sourceRepository,
IPackageRepository localRepository, IPackageConstraintProvider constraintProvider, String packageId,
SemanticVersion version, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
WARNING: NuGet:    at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage(String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
WARNING: NuGet:    at NuGet.Commands.InstallCommand.InstallPackage(IFileSystem fileSystem, String
packageId, SemanticVersion version)
WARNING: NuGet:    at NuGet.Program.Main(String[] args)
WARNING: NuGet: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '3.0.11' of package 'vlc'.
```

I'm sorry if it is a bit trivial question, but I have tried to get it to work properly for quite some time now and it is really bugging me. I have followed the installation procedure on the chocolatey website, and I have unregistered then registered chocolatey as a package source. Also, If I try to update it, it says I am already running the latest version (both for the power shell and choco). Is this normal? Should I just forget about it?... In all seriousness though, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you run `Get-PackageSource`?

Comment: Also, it could be possible that you have to install chocolatey-core.extension first? Disclaimer: I have zero experience with this, these are just guesses

Comment: I get both chocolatey & PSGallery as the 2 providers I have. As for the core extension, it has the same issue, using cmdlets it gives the same exact errors. But, if I use `choco` commands it says it is already installed. Could it be a path issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this issue too. It seems to be a problem with NuGet and TLS 1.3. Although I'm unsure if the first set of commands were needed or not, running them all did overcome the issue.

**Disable TLS 1.3**

```
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client' -Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
```

**Change .Net Framework default TLS version**

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
```

You may want to try the second set of commands first and if that does it alone I will update this answer.

[Source](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/7705)

Comment: That is odd, After running the 2 cmdlets for changing the .NET Framework default TLS. the error msg stopped showing, but the commands do nothing at all except just showing the package's Name, Version, Source and Summery. No installing, uninstalling or any operation of any kind executes, all cmdlets now just show the package info. After that I used the cmdlets for disabling TLS 1.3 but nothing happened, they had no effect whatsoever...

Comment: All vlc from choco is an installer. Go to c:\chocolaty and in the bin you’ll see vlc and  bat file to install it. Try a different app from chocolatey that actually installs

Comment: I tried sysinternals, atom and GIMP, too. All the same. A directory with the software's name is add to C:\chocolatey\lib   which contains a  **.nupkg** file with the software's name and a "tools" file which, in all the cases, contains a file called chocolateyinstall.ps1    Also, Nothing in the \bin  folder, and all these packages both install and uninstall normally using `choco install` & `choco uninstall`

Comment: I installed bluescreenview and it installed the app

Comment: Whether or not "install-package" does what "choco install" does was not the issue addressed by your post. The issue was being able to run the command successfully and it complete the task. Add -Verbose to confirm it's doing whatever it wasn't doing prior to your post. Then maybe ask the makers of chocolatey if this is what they intended for the cmdlet. Running `Install-Package -Name vlc -source chocolatey -Verbose` should confirm it's completing successfully.